# how to hide the count of individual attributes in pivot js?

Tags: javascript, pivot-table

I am using the following pivot js [library](https://pivottable.js.org/examples/)

refer the following [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nicolaskruchten/w86bgq9o/)

```
$("#output").pivotUI(
  $.pivotUtilities.tipsData, {
    rows: ["sex", "smoker"],
    cols: ["day", "time"],
    vals: ["tip", "total_bill"],
    aggregatorName: "Sum over Sum",
    rendererName: "Heatmap"
  });
```

Here we can drag drop attributes to the rows and columns which get reflected in the table, we can also click on the any attribute like 'smoker' and filter out the data, I want to know whether there is a way to hide the count that appears besides the data in smoker?[image: I want to hide the count beside No and Yes]

Comment: Inspect the code, get the css class for it, and override this class with a `display: none;`

Comment: the library that we are using doesn't allow us to provide custom classes for any elements, also if you see the example, the count next to Yes or No in the 'smoker' attribute doesn't have any class, I have a requirement where I specifically need to hide the count for a single attribute only for example 'smoker'.

Comment: That's the magic with javascript and css, your library doesn't need to allow you do something, it is your code and as such you can do whatever you want with it. I find it very hard to believe. In fact I looked at the provided sample and there is `<span class="count">(151)</span>` so it has classes. And that library in fact does support callback functions, so it is doable. https://pivottable.js.org/examples/simple_function.html